# WSO2 identity server 6.0.0 SOAP APIs Replacement

Tags: wso2-identity-server

**Describe the issue:**
As part of WSO2 identity server 6.0.0, SOAP APIs are Deprecated and Recommended to use REST-based APIs. We are using RemoteUserStoreManagerService.wsdl and UserIdentityManagementAdminService.wsdl SOAP APIs in our project, want to replace the SOAP APIs with recommended REST APIs. Can you help us to find the list of REST APIs to replace RemoteUserStoreManagerService.wsdl and UserIdentityManagementAdminService.wsdl SOAP APIs. The APIs document is not clear.

**Am referring the below document from wso2**
https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/references/about-this-release/#removed-features
https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/overview/

**Expected behavior:**
Can you help us to find the list of REST APIs to replace RemoteUserStoreManagerService.wsdl and UserIdentityManagementAdminService.wsdl SOAP APIs.

Answer (score 2):

Both `RemoteUserStoreManagerService.wsdl` and `UserIdentityManagementAdminService.wsdl` has user management operations.
So you should be able to find all REST APIs matching to your SOAP APIs under the `user Management` section of https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/overview/

`RemoteUserStoreManagerService.wsdl` service:

- For user-related CRUD operations (creation, read, update and delete), you can use SCIM2.0 /Users API
  https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/scim2-rest-apis/
- For role-related CRUD operations, you can user SCIM 2.0 /Roles API https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/scim2-rest-apis/

`UserIdentityManagementAdminService.wsdl` service:

- For user's identity claim management, you can use SCIM 2.0 /Users API. You have to change the payload with the relevant scim attributes mapped to the identity claims
- For the user's challenge question answers management, this API can be used
  https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/challenge-rest-api/