# Finding Replacement SOAP APIs for WSO2 identity server for 6.0.0 version

Tags: wso2

Describe the issue: As part of WSO2 identity server 6.0.0, SOAP APIs are Deprecated and Recommended to use REST-based APIs. We are using RemoteUserStoreManagerService.wsdl and UserIdentityManagementAdminService.wsdl SOAP APIs in our project, want to replace the SOAP APIs with recommended REST APIs. Can you help us to find the list of REST APIs to replace RemoteUserStoreManagerService.wsdl and UserIdentityManagementAdminService.wsdl SOAP APIs. The APIs document is not clear.

Requirement : We are unable to find the replacement for following APIs:
getUserClaims , updateUserLocale , updateUserClaim , retrieveUserRoles , getLastLoginTime
We want the data specific to a particular user by using userName or userId which is not available in WSO2 6.0.0
Can you help us to find the list of REST APIs.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/73692011/10055162

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SCIM2.0 /Users API](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/scim2-rest-apis/#/Users%20Endpoint) for user-related CRUD operations. Also for role related operations, you can use [SCIM 2.0 /Roles API](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/scim2-rest-apis/#/Roles%20Endpoint) and for group related operations, use [SCIM 2.0 /Groups API](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/scim2-rest-apis/#/Groups%20Endpoint).

To view user claims, user the [get user with id API](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/scim2-rest-apis/#/Users%20Endpoint/getUser%20by%20id). For update user claims you can either use the [patch operation](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/scim2-rest-apis/#/Users%20Endpoint/patchUser) or [put operation](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/scim2-rest-apis/#/Users%20Endpoint/updateUser). To update a single claim, patch operation is preferred.

Adding more to your question about the above soap APIs, they both are related to user management. All these APIs can be found in [here](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/overview/).