# Finding the replacement of the SOAP APIs for WSO2 identity server for 6.0.0 version

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

As part of WSO2 identity server 6.0.0, SOAP APIs are deprecated and recommended to use REST-based APIs. We are using RemoteUserStoreManagerService.wsdl and UserIdentityManagementAdminService.wsdl SOAP APIs in our project, want to replace the SOAP APIs with recommended REST APIs. Can you help us to find the list of REST APIs to replace RemoteUserStoreManagerService.wsdl and UserIdentityManagementAdminService.wsdl SOAP APIs. The APIs document is not clear.

We are unable to find the replacement for the claim management APIs which are specific to user.The APIs which are provided for the [Claim management](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/claim-management-rest-api/) are not user specific, we want to retrieve/create/delete the claims by passing username or userid in the request payload.
Can you please provide the details that are such APIs available for the claim management.

Answer (score 1):

The REST API that you have mentioned matches the ClaimMetadataManagementService.wsdl https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/develop/managing-claims-with-apis/

The only available REST API to manage user claims (retrieving, updating, deleting) is SCIM 2.0 Users APIs https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/scim2-rest-apis/#/Users%20Endpoint/getUser

The thing you have to keep in mind is that SCIM is a protocol that is used for user management. Even though you directly used the local claim URIs in SOAP services to manage user claims, in SCIM API calls you to have to use the respective SCIM claim that is mapped to the local claim.

Check the SCIM Claim Dialects by navigating to management console -> Main -> Identity -> Claims -> List.
There you can find the SCIM claim to local claim mapping

eg:
Get Specific user's name, username claims. Required attributes should be added to attributes param based on the SCIM protocol:

GET `https://localhost:9443/scim2/Users/<user-id>?attributes=username,name`

Add user claims:
Refer https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/scim2-patch-operations/#add-user-attributes
and https://medium.com/p/1c43bb218658

Delete user claims:
Refer https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/scim2-patch-operations/#remove-user-attributes
and https://medium.com/p/1c43bb218658

Comment: I tried the patch operation for user claims using this document, 
https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/scim2-patch-operations/#add-user-attributes and https://medium.com/p/1c43bb218658 for adding the claims for the user ,

I am giving the below payload 
{
 { 
 "schemas": 
 [ "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:PatchOp" ],
 "Operations":
  [ 
   { "op": "replace",
   "path": "urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User:country", 
   "value": "India" 
   } 
  ] 
 }

Comment: We are using this API from SCIM 2.0 API https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/6.0.0/apis/restapis/scim2.yaml 
 https://localhost:9443/t/carbon.super/scim2/Users/user
 We are giving error as,
 {

    "schemas": [

        "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:Error"

    ],

    "detail": "text/plain is not supported.",

    "status": "406"

}
 Is The correct API and payload been used?

Comment: Seems you have used `--header 'Content-Type: text/plain' `. You have to use application/json as the Content-Type in request header(`--header 'Content-Type: application/json'`) because payload is json

Comment: Unable to update claims with the patch operation, sending the below payload.
{

"schemas": [

  "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:PatchOp"

],

"Operations": [

       {

            "op": "replace",

           "path":"http://wso2.org/claims/givenname",

           "value":"KIMMY"

}

    ]
  }

Comment: getting below response,
{

    "schemas": [

        "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:Error"

    ],

    "scimType": "noTarget",

    "detail": "No such attribute with the name : http",

    "status": "400"

}
Can you please check what is the issue, what path we need to give for updating claims.

Comment: You can't use local claim URIs with SCIM API calls. As mentioned in the answer you have to use the mapped scim claims. If you want to update the givenName of the user path should be`"path":"name.givenName"` instead of `path":"wso2.org/claims/givenname"`

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue was raised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73729782/finding-replacement-soap-apis-for-wso2-identity-server-for-6-0-0-version). Check the first answer.

The doc that you have referred is to manage the claims in general. Refer to the introduction paragraph.

The [API overview](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/apis/overview/) page contains all the information about all the APIs you need. The following image shows the APIs needed to mange users, roles and groups (More than what you have asked in the question).

[image]

NOTE: Better not to use SCIM1.1